# Android app is crashing but i can't reproduce the error. It looks like a native crash

Tags: android, crash, native, anr

I have a crash in crashlytics and i can't reproduce it all the time. This crash started since i updated the app to API lvl 32.

Target versions:

```
minSdkVersion 21
targetSdkVersion 32
compileSdkVersion 32
```

Here are some information about the crash. There is a long file so i will upload the last lines of code i see in crashlytics. The file is kinda long to upload it here i think. If you need more info let me know please.

```
Signal Catcher (runnable):tid=6 systid=8150 
#00 pc 0x377c45 libart.so (art::DumpNativeStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, int, BacktraceMap*, char const*, art::ArtMethod*, void*, bool) + 76)
#01 pc 0x446fc7 libart.so (art::Thread::DumpStack(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const + 386)
#02 pc 0x442993 libart.so (art::Thread::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool, BacktraceMap*, bool) const + 34)
#03 pc 0x45f569 libart.so (art::DumpCheckpoint::Run(art::Thread*) + 664)
#04 pc 0x45ab43 libart.so (art::ThreadList::RunCheckpoint(art::Closure*, art::Closure*) + 354)
#05 pc 0x45a07b libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool) + 1486)
#06 pc 0x459775 libart.so (art::ThreadList::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) + 604)
#07 pc 0x411eeb libart.so (art::Runtime::DumpForSigQuit(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&) + 130)
#08 pc 0x421aa3 libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::HandleSigQuit() + 1046)
#09 pc 0x420e3b libart.so (art::SignalCatcher::Run(void*) + 290)
#10 pc 0xaaf33 libc.so (__pthread_start(void*) + 40)
#11 pc 0x642e3 libc.so (__start_thread + 30)

Jit thread pool worker thread 0 (native):tid=7 systid=8151 
#00 pc 0x5e4a8 libc.so (syscall + 28)
#01 pc 0x131bb3 libart.so (art::ConditionVariable::WaitHoldingLocks(art::Thread*) + 82)
#02 pc 0x460a87 libart.so (art::ThreadPool::GetTask(art::Thread*) + 58)
#03 pc 0x460199 libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run() + 72)
#04 pc 0x45fdd9 libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*) + 116)
#05 pc 0xaaf33 libc.so (__pthread_start(void*) + 40)
#06 pc 0x642e3 libc.so (__start_thread + 30)
```

Since i upgraded the app to android 12 and i started testing it now i have a crash that i can't reproduce it all the time.
I tested on two different devices:
Galaxy A32/ Android 12
Galaxy Tab A / Android 11

Comment: That's a SIG_QUIT.  That signal is made when another app requests to kill the app.  The usual way to get this is in terminals when someone hits ctrl-c.  Someone is purposely killing your app

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer but still, this is really confusing form me. I'm a self taught android dev and i have only few months of experience. I will try to investigate more about this SIG_QUIT. If there is someone else and can explain it or give me some solution i will appreciate it.

Comment: SIG_QUIT is actually a Unix/Linux thing.  Android is Linux underneath it all.  You'll likely have more luck looking into it from that end than from Android.